# Calculate time interval based on conditions in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, datetime

I have a time series dataframe `df` as below:

```
                        id      timestamp                data   Date         sig      events1   Start   Peak   gradient 
timestamp                                   
2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 40250   2020-01-15 06:12:49.213  20.0   2020-01-15  -1.0      0.0       NaN     1.0    0.000148
2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 40251   2020-01-15 06:12:49.313  19.5   2020-01-15   1.0      1.0       0.0     0.0    0.000294
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 40256   2020-01-15 08:05:10.083  20.0   2020-01-15   1.0      0.0       1.0     0.0    0.000339
2020-01-15 08:05:10.183 40257   2020-01-15 08:05:10.183  20.5   2020-01-15   1.0      0.0       0.0     0.0    0.000334
2020-01-15 09:01:50.993 40310   2020-01-15 09:01:50.993  21.0   2020-01-15   1.0      0.0       0.0     0.0    0.000000
2020-01-15 09:01:51.093 40311   2020-01-15 09:01:51.093  21.5   2020-01-15   1.0      0.0       0.0     0.0   -0.008618
```

I would like to find, for every `Start==1` row, until the next `Start==1` row, the duration (in seconds) that it takes from its current `data` to reach `data>=40` if `data` ever happens to reach `40`. If `data` never reached 40, then output `0`. What is a good way to do it?

Comment: You probably want to start with a function that slices your df in "start to next start" sub-dataframes. Then, independently, you have a function to parse the data and calculate the time.

Comment: @Guimoute Could you please recommend some functions/packages I could use for slicing the sub-dataframes in this case? Do I need a for-loop? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to give an example of the expected output? What do you mean by he duration (in seconds) that it takes from its current data to reach data>=40?

Comment: @wwnde For example, in the data provided, `2020-01-15 08:05:10.083` is where `Start` is `1`, so this is the start time, I want to see if `data` ever reaches `40` and how long it takes from the start time. Let's say `data` reached `40` at `2020-01-15 08:05:22.083`, then the duration would be 12 seconds. If it didn't reach `40` before the next `Start ==1` , then output `0` or `NaN`.

Comment: See my belated response. Perth gets too busy at times. Went the long way. You probably could get a shorter route out there.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated my own data:

```
np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-25', periods=15, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Timestamp': rng, 'data': [1,2,3,4,5,40,47,8,9,10,30,12,13,40,20], 'id':[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] }) 
df
```

Group based on id cluster using [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

```
df['group']  = df['id'].cumsum().reindex()
df
```

Select start of each group into another dataframe `df2` and rename Timestamp to Date

```
df2=df[df.id.eq(1) & df.id.shift(-1).eq(0)]
df2.drop(columns=['data','id'], inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'Timestamp':'Date'}, inplace=True)
```

Merge new dataframe `df2` with `df` and  coerce Date back to datetime

```
result = pd.merge(df, df2, on='group', how='outer')
result['Date']=pd.to_datetime(result['Date'])
result
```

mask all instances where `data==40`

```
n =df['data']==40
```

Applying the mask, calculate the time lapse between `start=1` to when `data==40` if it ever does. Prudent that you drop `Date` because we are done with it

```
result['x']=result.loc[n,'Timestamp']-result.loc[n,'Date']
result.drop(columns=['Date'],inplace=True)
result
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hi wwnde, thank you for the detailed solution! I couldn't understand why `x` for second time hitting `40` is `00:01:00` instead of `00:06:00` (from `00:07:00` to `00:13:00`) though? Hope you're well in Perth :)

Comment: because, my understanding is that it is is timestamp@ data==40 minus timestamp@start==1 in that group.

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry I didn't read it properly. Please allow me to apply it on my data.

Comment: Is it possible to limit it to the first reading that `data==40` for each group? So if there is a second row @ `data==40` in the same group we will ignore it and skip to the next group.

Comment: Hi I found a way using `result = result.groupby('group').first()`. Thank you so much!

Comment: I hadnt seen your comment.If you're happy that is fine. Thanks for giving me an opportunity to work on this wonderful problem